# Problem in mysql query using Union all with time-range

Tags: sql, mysql, time-series

I have two queries with `Union All` clause as you can see below,

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) as RESULT FROM ( 
   SELECT 
        json_object(  
              "points", json_arrayagg(json_array(
                            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamping)*1000, 
                            CONVERT(ROUND(P1,4), DECIMAL(9,4))
             ))                                   
         ) AS obj
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        timestamping between '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z' 
    AND 
        '2022-05-10T23:59:59.999Z'

     UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        json_object(
              "datapoints", json_arrayagg(json_array(
                            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamping)*1000, 
                            CONVERT(ROUND(P2,4), DECIMAL(9,4))
               ))                                   
         ) AS obj
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        timestamping between '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z' 
    AND 
        '2022-05-10T23:59:59.999Z'
) x
```

Result is null as show below,

[image]

But but but

If I execute above two queries one by one, I mean without using `Union All`, it executes successfully as shown below,

1st query,

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) as RESULT FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        json_object(
                     
              "points", json_arrayagg(json_array(
                            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamping)*1000, 
                            CONVERT(ROUND(P1,4), DECIMAL(9,4))
             ))                                   
         ) AS obj
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        timestamping between '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z' 
    AND 
        '2022-05-10T23:59:59.999Z'
) x
```

Yes, above query works.

2nd query,

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) as RESULT FROM ( 
                       
    SELECT 
        json_object(
        
          "datapoints", json_arrayagg(json_array(
                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamping)*1000, 
                        CONVERT(ROUND(P2,4), DECIMAL(9,4))
           ))                                   
         ) AS obj
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        timestamping between '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z' 
    AND 
        '2022-05-10T23:59:59.999Z'
) x
```

Yes, it works.

I don't know what's is wrong. Not able to identify.

**Basically, If I increase time period, it stops working. With small date-range, it works.**

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/_qHgsrsO)** - Just for reference as I can't reproduce the actual problem with sample data.

**NOTE** : In Top code snippet (with `union all` clause example), If I change end time from `2022-05-10T23:59:59.999Z` to `2022-05-09T23:59:59.999Z` then with `union all` also, it works.

Comment: How much is the data for date 2022-05-10T23:59:59.999Z?
Is there very large data diff between the two dates?

Comment: If I execute normal mysql query, the count I get is '317472'

Comment: Could be too large to display? Side note: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), you should use half-open date ranges instead.

Comment: It sounds like a size limit in `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`, but there's no limit documented (other than the general `max_allowed_packet` that affects all queries). Or it could be a bug.

Comment: @Charlieface if you can elaborate.

Comment: @Barmar even I suspect the same but I have many sensors eg p1, p1.....p100000. User can select any number of sensors and any date-range. How can I make sure `max_allowed_packet` always returns data ?

Answer (score 0):

UNION queries try to return widest data type for a column that would cover all datatypes for this column from the corresponding selects.

If datetime related function is used, the resultant data type is an internal datetime type, having a microsecond part.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. if you could extend it.

Comment: The column datatype is `JSON` in both subqueries in the UNION. No widening should be needed.